# Find the expected value of the number of $i,j,k$ triplets such that $a_i<a_j<a_k$ in a permutation

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The task is to find the expected value of the number of $i,j,k$ triplets such that $a_i<a_j<a_k$ in a permutation.

I've the following:

Let $\xi_{ijk}=\begin{cases}1, & \text{if $a_i<a_j<a_k$} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then $\xi$, which is the number of triplets that satisfy the condition is:
$$\xi=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \xi_{ijk}$$
And the expected value is:
$$E\xi=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n} E\xi_{ijk}$$
However, I do not follow how to find $E\xi_{ijk}$.

I've noticed that $\xi_{ijk}=\eta_{ij}\cdot\eta_{jk}$, where $\eta_{ij}=\begin{cases}1, & \text{if $a_i<a_j$} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, but $E(\eta_{ij}\cdot\eta_{jk})=E\eta_{ij}\cdot E\eta_{jk}$ holds only if $\eta_{ij}$ and $\eta_{jk}$ are independent, which I can't prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a random permutation, all six permutations of numbers $a_i,a_j,a_k$ are equally probable. So probability that $a_i<a_j<a_k$ is $1/6$. And therefore 
$$
\mathbb E\xi_{ijk}=1\cdot \mathbb P(a_i<a_j<a_k) = \frac16.
$$

The same time it proves that $\eta_{ij}$ and $\eta_{jk}$ are dependent since $\mathbb E\eta_{ij}\cdot \mathbb E\eta_{jk}=\frac12\cdot\frac12\neq \frac16$.

Answer (score 1):

If $i$, $j$, and $k$ are all different numbers, then  $a_i$, $a_j$ and $a_k$ are all different since we are dealing with a permutation. Therefore, for every triple of different variables, there is exactly one arrangement in which the values are in ascending order.  Therefore, there are $\binom n3$ such triples.